# How to resolve this error in google earth engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

Error

> Too many pixels in the region. Found 30698755252, but maxPixels allows
> only 10000000000. Ensure that you are not aggregating at a higher
> resolution than you intended; that is a frequent cause of this error.
> If not, then you may set the 'maxPixels' argument to a limit suitable
> for your computation; set 'bestEffort' to true to aggregate at
> whatever scale results in 'maxPixels' total pixels; or both.

The main code I received the error:

```
 features = features.reproject({crs: aspect.projection().crs(), scale: 30}).float()
 var minMax = features.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 10e9})
print(minMax)
```

Comment: It means that you are trying to do an operation on too many pixels. Select a smaller geometry to do the reduceRegion.

Answer (score 4):

The error message says it all.

You are trying attempting to aggregate ~30e9 pixels but your `maxPixels` is set to 10e9. Just increase `maxPixels` by setting `maxPixels: 40e9` and the code will work fine.